# why my bootstrap can't work

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I try to use the `modal` plugin,but there is not effect.I see the code,the place is okay.So there is something in my code,but the turtal I see.. So help me,give me some advice.

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
        <link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="docs/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="sgsheg/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="sgsheg/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="modal hide fade">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="model" aria-hidden="true" >&times;</button>
            <h3>Modal header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: What's actually wrong? Your example seems fine. Did you forget to put `data-dismiss="modal"` on your "Close" and "Save changes" buttons? Note that you misspelled `data-dismiss="model"` on your "x" close button

Comment: "but the turtal I see". You're seeing turtles?

Comment: @j08691: re-tag as a [logo](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/logo) question?

Comment: sorry, I write a little fuzzy! the question to me is that,i want use the bootstrap api to make the pop box,but no result

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `toggle`r

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
```

Or you can fire it manually

```
$(function(){
  $(".modal").modal("show"); //shows the modal on document ready
  //$(".some-class").on('click' , function() { //this is if you want to fire it with a button
  //   $(".modal").modal("show");              //of course you don't have to use both data-*
  //}                                          //and javascript, choose one.  
}
```

It depends on what you have to do;

if you have to `show` the `modal` when the `doc` is ready, use `javascript`, if not use only `html` instead.

**UPDATE** 
include only `bootstrap.js` or `bootstrap-modal`, not togheter.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Thyme leaf engine needs the script **src** definitions specified as

```
th:src="@{...}"
```

So try

```
th:src="@{sgsheg/jquery-1.10.0.min.js}"
th:src="@{sgsheg/bootstrap.min.js}"
```

Also, you really don't need to include bootstrap-modal.js because it is already in `bootstrap.min.js`

And if you've defined your `resourceHandler as "/sgsheg/**" and "/js/**"` then you need to put the slashes (/) in front of the **src url.**